# is there a way to discover local network devices in a Adobe Flex Mobile app

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, bonjour, upnp

I am trying to write an app for iOS and Android platforms, that discovers local network devices like printers, tv, computers etc.

I would love to use bonjour, but apparently Bonjour can't be used on Android devices (?) when writing an app in adobe flex framework.

Comment: the question is, the title: is there a way to discover local network devices in a Adobe Flex Mobile app, sorry for forgetting the questions mark :P

Comment: @Marci-man I don't believe these APIs are exposed via AIR.  If the underlying OS exposes this information then you can use a NativeExtension to collect the data.

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing a technical reason why you can't use Bonjour on Android?  Some security block?

If not, you may be able to work directly from AIR--[Renaun Erickson has a blog post](http://renaun.com/blog/2010/03/using-air-20-to-find-services-through-mdnszeroconf-bonjour/) that attempts to do the same (which I haven't tried).